# Crossing the Universe

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Would you think I'll ever change?
Or am I gonna stay the same?
Refrain from nothing, I'll maintain,
Like my Beatles, I'll remain,
Do you have five words to chain?

Comment: I believe the question is to make a sentence with 5 words??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is

> "**Nothing's gonna change my world**"

Would you think I'll ever change?
Or am I gonna stay the same?
Refrain from nothing, I'll maintain,
Like my Beatles, I'll remain,
Do you have five words to chain?

> From the Beatles' song *Across the Universe* hinted at in the question's title, there are lyrics "Nothing's gonna change my world...".  These are part of the **refrain** of the song.  Also, the first letters of each line (5 words to chain) spell WORLD.

Comment: Good. I'm going to give credit here because you obviously got it, but everything specifically pointed to 'Nothing's gonna change my world" as the answer itself. I'm looking for the 'refrain' specifically. This one was perhaps too easy or kludgy, but note that every word is also in the puzzle itself. Good job!